# Properties of a linear transformation satisfying a certain equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation satisfying $T^3-3T^2=-2I$, where $I:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is the identity transformation. Which of the following statements are true?

$1.$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ must admit a basis $\mathcal{B}_1$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}_1$ is symmetric.

$2.$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ must admit a basis $\mathcal{B}_2$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}_2$ is upper triangular.

$3.$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ must contain a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Tv=v$.

$4.$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ must contain two linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2$ such that $Tv_1=v_1$ and $Tv_2=v_2$.

I know that here $x^3-3x^2+2$ is an annihilating polynomial. Also $x^3-3x^2+2=(x-1)(x-(1+\sqrt{3}))(x-(1-\sqrt{3}))$. Now let $P(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. We see that $P(x)$ can be factored into distinct linear factors. This implies that $T$ is a diagonalizable operator. From this I got stuck.

Comment: (1) and (2) should be straightforward from the work that you did regarding diagonalizability. What are (3) and (4) really saying? Hint: think eigenvalues.

Comment: Diagonal matrices are symmetric and upper triangular.